# What was Sarah Bartowski's (née Walker) birth name?

Tags: names, chuck

Did Sarah Walker Bartowski reveal her birth name?

And in which episode did they get married?
And in which episode did they realise they were in love?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sarah never revealed her full birth name.  The most we learn is that her given names were Sam (probably short for Samantha, Chuck versus the Fake Name, season 3, episode 8) and Lisa (Chuck versus the Wookiee, Season 1, episode 4).  Her father is introduced as Jack Burton (Chuck versus the Delorean, season 2, episode 10), and we know Jenny Burton was an alias of Sarah's (Chuck versus the Cougars, season 2, episode 4) but both are fake identities.

Sarah and Chuck get married at the end of Seasin 4 (episode 24, Chuck vs the Cliffhanger).  The first "confirmation" of mutual feelings between Chuck and Sarah (rather than implied feelings and/or comments from Carina or Casey) is a kiss initiated by Sarah at the end of Chuck versus the Imported Hard Salami (season 1, episode 9).